# Data tables showing all records instead of pagination while giving data through server json

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatables

This is my json output.

```
{
    "draw": 0,
    "recordsTotal": 130,
    "recordsFiltered": 130,
    "data": [
        {
            "order_id": "32",
            "location_address": "XYZ road Delhi delhi",
            "order_status": "0",
            "created_by": "5",
            "from_date": "Mar-30-2015",
            "emp_name": " ",
            "actions": "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<a onclick=\"show_edit()\" class=\"btn default btn-xs purple \">\r\n                                               <i class=\"fa fa-edit\" ></i> Edit </a>"
        },
        {
            "order_id": "33",
            "location_address": "XYZ road Delhi delhi",
            "order_status": "0",
            "created_by": "5",
            "from_date": "Mar-30-2015",
            "emp_name": " Ranjeet thakur, abhijeet thakur",
            "actions": "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<a onclick=\"show_edit()\" class=\"btn default btn-xs purple \">\r\n                                               <i class=\"fa fa-edit\" ></i> Edit </a>"
        },
        {
            "order_id": "34",
            "location_address": "XYZ road Delhi delhi",
            "order_status": "0",
            "created_by": "5",
            "from_date": "Mar-31-2015",
            "emp_name": " ",
            "actions": "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<a onclick=\"show_edit()\" class=\"btn default btn-xs purple \">\r\n                                               <i class=\"fa fa-edit\" ></i> Edit </a>"
        },
        {
            "order_id": "35",
            "location_address": "XYZ road Delhi delhi",
            "order_status": "0",
            "created_by": "5",
            "from_date": "Mar-31-2015",
            "emp_name": " super Employee",
            "actions": "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<a onclick=\"show_edit()\" class=\"btn default btn-xs purple \">\r\n                                               <i class=\"fa fa-edit\" ></i> Edit </a>"
        },
        {
            "order_id": "36",
            "location_address": "XYZ road Delhi delhi",
            "order_status": "0",
            "created_by": "5",
            "from_date": "Mar-31-2015",
            "emp_name": " ",
            "actions": "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<a onclick=\"show_edit()\" class=\"btn default btn-xs purple \">\r\n                                               <i class=\"fa fa-edit\" ></i> Edit </a>"
        }
    ]
}
```

"pageLength": 10 (It should show 10 records on a single page.)

Still its showing 130 records on one page. But i want to show 10 records on a single page.. So how can I show..?

Initialization of Plugin :-

```
dataTable: { 
                "lengthMenu": [
                    [10, 20, 50, 100, 150, -1],
                    [10, 20, 50, 100, 150, "All"] 
                ],
                "pageLength": 10,
    aoColumns: [
    { mData: 'order_id'},
    { mData: 'user_name'},
    { mData: 'location_address'},
    { mData: 'from_date'},
    { mData: 'assign_to'},
       { mData: 'order_status'},
    { mData: 'actions'}
    ],

"ajax": {
                    "url": page.php,
                }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are initializing the plugin?

Comment: Just a minute.. I'll paste

Comment: I have updated question with what you asked for. Please help me.

Comment: is this a jquery plugin?? dont assume we know what youre talking about off the bat. provide all your JS function and as much detail possible

Comment: Have you tried adding `"paging": true,` right before `"pageLength": 10,`? You'll also need something like `"dom": '<"top">t<"bottom">p<"clear">'` to show the pagination buttons at the bottom of the chart.

Comment: the fields in the JSON does not entirely match the fields aoColumns - it will fail initialization anyway, just saying.